# How can I set those values to List<Models> after returning from a response on the server?

Tags: java, android

I am working on Http API that response values from the server. My problem is that the response sends string values as like that without JSON object.

```
Username:password:level
user1:user1:2
user2:user2:2
user3:user3:2
user4:user4:2
```

nothing else. So,

```
List<Models> model;
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>;
String[] couple=response.split(":");
for (int i = 3; i < couple.length - 1; i++) {
     items = couple[i].split("\n");
     String models = gson.toJson(items[0]);
     Log.d(TAG, "a is ----> \t" + models);
     stringList.add(models);

}
model = (List)stringList;
```

The logcat shows something like that:

```
  a is  ---->   user1
  a is  ---->   2
  a is  ---->   user2
  a is  ---->   2
```

Models Class is :

```
public class Models{
    private static final String TAG = Models.class.getName();

    private String mUserName;
    private String mPassword;
    private int mlevel;

    public Models(){

    }

    public String getmUserName() {
        return mUserName;
    }

    public void setmUserName(String mUserName) {
        this.mUserName = mUserName;
    }

    public String getmPassword() {
        return mPassword;
    }

    public void setmPassword(String mPassword) {
        this.mPassword = mPassword;
    }

    public int getMlevel() {
        return mlevel;
    }

    public void setMlevel(int mlevel) {
        this.mlevel = mlevel;
    }
```

I do not know how to deal with it.

Comment: can you add the Models class so we can understand what do you exactly want

Comment: @SayedEl-Abady I edited my question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split()` to parse the string yourself:

```
List<Models> models = new ArrayList<>();
String[] lines = result.split("\n");
for (String line : lines) {
    String[] items = line.split(":");
    Model model = new Models();
    model.setmUserName(items[0]);
    model.setmPassword(items[1]);
    model.setMlevel(Integer.valueOf(items[2]);
    models.add(model);
}
```

A word about names:

1. `Models` should be renamed `User` since this more accurately describes what the model represents.
2. Get rid of the `m` prefix of your member variables and the `m` in all accessors. For example, accessors should be named `getPassword()` and `setPassword()`, not `getmPasword()` and `setmPassword()`.

Answer (score 3):

May be you should split with "\n" first to get each row, and then split with ":" to get each coloum, such like this

```
    String[] couple = result.split("\n");
    for (int i = 1; i < couple.length; i++) {
        String[] items = couple[i].split(":");
        Log.e("Look Here:", "a is ----> \t" + items[0] + "," + items[1] + ","  + items[2]);
    }
```

hopes to be useful